# How to test whether port forwarding is working?

Tags: server, port-forwarding

I have done port forwarding on my computer but I don't know how to test it. Can anyone help me? I have not done it using iptables but I have done it by following the instructions given in [this link.](http://portforward.com/english/routers/port_forwarding/Sterlite/SAM300-AX/Apache.htm)

Comment: You can also use web app for checking port forwarding: http://www.yougetsignal.com/tools/open-ports/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> If you have setup a port forward on your Ubuntu, you can test it by
>   running port forwarding tests on websites specialized in this job. One
>   of these is [How to test port forwarding](http://www.yougetsignal.com/tools/open-ports/). It automatically detects
>   your IP and you have to enter only your port you are about to test,
>   and hit Check.

<sup>Source:ubuntu-for-humans</sup>

ubuntu-for-humans

Answer (score 0):

I find  websites like http://www.yougetsignal.com/tools/open-ports/ may not give the correct result if you don't have your server service running. On my Windows box, uttorrent says the port is open, but the website says it is closed. With ubuntu, you can use Transmission (often installed by default in Desktop version) to check ìf a port is open. The function used to check is in Edit/Preferences/Network.

Answer (score 0):

I use and prefer these test tools:

- https://www.grc.com/shieldsup
- https://www.yougetsignal.com/tools/open-ports/

If you have a wifi hotspot or your neighbor will allow you internet access, try accessing the port of interest from the WAN.